# Ciabatta with no air bubbles

Tags: baking, bread, italian-cuisine, proofing

My first time making Ciabatta...

Any ideas why my ciabatta is lacking air bubbles? It tastes nice and light.

It also didn’t rise as much as I’d expected.

I proofed airtight for 90 minutes then open air on a baking sheet for about 35 minutes.

I did notice the initial mix was really wet. Maybe a tad too much water I’m thinking?

Edit:
Recipe - I halved it and followed it exactly. 
https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/easy_ciabatta_98431

Comment: Ciabatta is supposed to be very wet, and stay very wet as well. It's also very sensitive to rough treatment once proofed, if you could edit and add details on the recipe and method you used we may be able to help. Did you add more flour than the recipe said?

Comment: Edited. I followed the recipe exactly for half the yield.

Comment: Hmmm. The recipes I’ve used in the past have started with a biga, rested overnight. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biga_(bread_baking)